# Accessing a single value for specific key pair from object in a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects with student information, I want to get a single value that is attached to a particular key using array.map
Here's the code

```
let balanceInfo = students.map((student) => {
    if (typeof(student) === Object){
       let balance = student.balance;
       return balance;
    } 
}) 
console.log(balanceInfo)
```

Where:
`students` is an array of objects
`.balance` is a key in the object

When the array is being traversed, I want to get the balance details of each student.

Comment: Please provide array of `students` and expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is mostly correct, but there is a small issue with the `typeof` check. The `typeof` operator returns a string, so the comparison should be with the string `'object'` rather than the `Object` constructor. Here's the corrected code:

```js
let balanceInfo = students.map((student) => {
    if (typeof student === 'object') {
        let balance = student.balance;
        return balance;
    }
});

console.log(balanceInfo);
```

This code will iterate over the `students` array using `map` and extract the `balance` property from each object. The resulting `balanceInfo` array will contain all the balance values.

Comment: Ah, nice explanation honestly, I couldn't write something similar ;-;

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `typeof(student) === Object`, you should write the `object` word in lowercase with quotes like `"object"`.

```js
let students = [
    {
        balance: 100,
    },
    {
        balance: 200,
    },
];

let balanceInfo = students.map((student) => {
    if (typeof student === "object") {
        let balance = student.balance;
        return balance;
    }
});

console.log(balanceInfo);
```

Answer (score 0):

From your `.map()` it looks like you want the balance of all the students.
If you want only balance printed in, you can put console while iterating the `students` array

```
students.forEach((student) => {
    console.log(student.balance)
})
```